# Rather complex PHP to Twig string conversion

Tags: php, twig

I have a string I'm having trouble converting to twig, I've already tried the PHP to twig converters and am having no luck. Any ideas on how to format this in twig?

```
<?php $string = strtr($model, array('-R' => '', '-r' => '', ' ' => '', '-reconditioned' => ''));  ?>
```

Comment: what is the string you want to format

Comment: I need to pass the value from $string in the php code above into twig syntax

Comment: what is not working in this? is your `$model` a string

Comment: I'm working in OpenCart and it uses twig files so anything in the <?php ?> syntax gets ignored

Answer (score 0):

The filter `replace` uses `strt` as underlaying function, as seen in the [source](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/2.x/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php#L447) of `twig`

```
 {{ example | replace({ '-r': '', '-R': '', '-reconditioned': '',}) }}
```